# shopify featured image super blurry

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have this line of code: `{{ product.featured_image | img_url | img_tag }}`

The problem with this is the image is extremely blurry. When I view the image from the shopify product dashboard, everything looks fine.

Any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pas the size for the `img_url` filter.

Example: `img_url: '600x'` or `img_url: '2048x'` what ever width you need.

If you don't pass anything it fallback to 100x100 if I remember correctly.

Comment: Just figured it out and saw this message. Thanks for answering still!